# Is it possible to color code intellisense like CSS?

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense

Consider the following screenshot:

[image]

Is it possible to apply the quick-reference color underline to other things, such as an enum when referenced? Perhaps something like this:

[image]

I know you can add custom summaries for methods etc:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Method summary here
    /// Author: andersleet
    /// www: http://example.com
    /// Compatibility: .NET 3.0 and later.
    /// </summary>
```

Is there an argument where you can specify colors?

Thanks!

Comment: That's not a Visual Studio feature.  It's probably from Resharper or similar.

Comment: Oh OK; I wasn't sure if this was added in the 2013 edition of the software. I have only used 2010 and earlier, and just recently got ReSharper.

Comment: You can write a VS extension to do that; for an example, see Web Essentials.  For C# code, you'll want Roslyn in VS 2015.

Comment: @SLaks - Thanks I'll definitely check that out.